# I cannot select a category in a web content. (Liferay 7.4.2)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to select a category in a web content in Liferay 7.4.2, but I cannot select it. I installed:

1. Liferay 7.4.2-g3 CE Bundle
2. JDK 8u221
3. MySQL 8.0

In the "Category" option, I create a vocabulary and a category.

**1. Vocabulary**

[image: vocabulary]

**2. Category**

[image: category]

[image: category details]

In the web content option, a structure is created with the "title", "content" and "image" fields.

[image: structure]

In creating web content, the structure is selected. In the "Categorization" option, the field to select the category is not displayed.

[image: web content]

The problem is that I cannot select the category in the web content. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Regards!

Comment: Did you specify the asset type when you created the Noticia vocabulary?

Comment: Yes, I have selected "All Asset Types" in the "Noticia" vocabulary and I can't select the category in the web contet. I have the edited the question with new screenshots of the vocabulary, category and web content.

Comment: Have you reindexed, Journal articles, Vocabulary, and categories?

Answer (score 2):

When creating a vocabulary, you have to specify to which asset type it is related to.[image]

You can edit *Noticia* vocabulary and associate it to the structure of your web content or you can associate it to "All Asset Types".

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and created many categories and set All Asset Types but still not showing in the right sidebar. There must be a bug. I repeated the same steps in different installation and it worked.